# ultimate visual studio. Installs mvc3 but doesnt show it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to create a new project, and go to web, no mvc project appears for me to choose.

Why is that? and why the microsoft installer says that the mvc3 is installed at the end of the installation, but actually, the installation isnt installed, cause I cant create any mvc project :(

UPDATE:

i tried another asp.net mvc3 installer and it gave me this at the end of the installation.

Error:

> OS Version = 5.1.2600, Platform 2, Service Pack 3 OS Description =
>   WinXP - x86 Professional Service Pack 3 CommandLine =
>   j:\temp\ext47334\setup.exe TimeZone = Jerusalem Standard Time Initial
>   LCID = 1033 Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
>   Operation: Installing Package Name = Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Package
>   Version = 3.0.20105.0 User Experience Data Collection Policy:
>   UserControlled Number of applicable items: 3 Exe
>   (j:\temp\ext47334\VS10-KB2483190-x86.exe) succeeded. MSI
>   (j:\temp\ext47334\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi) Installation failed. Msi
>   Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC
>   3_20120224_101806156-MSI_AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi.txt Final Result:
>   **Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during**
>   installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:02:56).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 uses a Web Application template and not a WebSite. So go to `File -> New Project` and not `File -> Web Site ...` or simply use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+N</kbd>:

[image]

in contrast to a new Web Site:

[image]

Comment: yup..that doesnt appear...I know how to create a project..I did it before..but I re-installed visual studio..and installed mvc..it doesnt work

Comment: @BlackFire27, it seems that you haven't installed ASP.NET MVC 3 properly. Try removing all installed versions and try downloading the full installer package instead of using the Platform Web installer.

Comment: may be I should reinstall all windows instead? where is the link to the full installer package? see my update above

Comment: @BlackFire27, here's the link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491 Once again, make sure you uninstall all previous versions that might have corrupted your system.

Comment: Thanks..I will reinstall the windows system if this doesnt work..I have no choice

Comment: Thanks, your advice worked..I uninstaleld and then reinstalled mvc 3

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the .net Framework version in the dropdown at the top of the add new project box?  The ASP MVC new project types only show up when .net Framework 4 is selected.

Comment: Are the templates phyiscally on disk - depending on settings should be somewhere like. c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033

Comment: I dont see any rar file in that path that is named mvc.. could you post me a working link of where i can download and install,,a working installer of the mvc framework

Comment: The one we used was http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491 but if your install is failing that might not help.  What's in the logfile that your update post mentions?

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me in the past, and its always been down to VS settings:

- Check that you have C# selected as your language.
- Check that you have .Net 4.0 (or higher) selected as your platform

Comment: even when i type mvc in the search box..nothing comes out

Comment: it definitely say ".Net Framework 4" in the top combo box on http://i.stack.imgur.com/eij8N.png?

Comment: yeah..I am sure..I think i can even provide a photo..look at my update